# Как правильно назвать стили по БЭМ?

Tags: css, бэм

Знакомлюсь с понятием БЭМ. Есть боковое меню: сверху лого, ниже сами пукнты меню (каждый пункт состоит из иконки и текста рядом)
Назвал так:

```
.side-bar // блок
.side-bar__logo // элемент - лого
.side-bar__item // элемент - пункт меню
```

и тут появляется вопрос, как назвать стили для иконки и текста пункта меню? side-bar__icon и side-bar__text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.side-bar
  .side-bar__logo
    .logo
  .side-bar__menu
    .menu
      .menu__item
        .menu__ico
        .menu__name
      .menu__item
        .menu__ico
        .menu__name
```